# Custom Fonts on Heroku with Django/Python

Tags: python, django, heroku, font-face

I'm using custom fonts from Pixeden, which are similar to FontAwesome. For some reason, the custom font-faces are not rendering, though I've placed all of the necessary files in my static folder. How do you get custom fonts working on Heroku with Python?

I'm using Django Storages, Django Pipeline, and Amazon S3.

Comment: have you declare the font faces from css file ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll reply because I have had this problem lately and I resolved it. If you are using a font for example from googleapis in your html page, just remove `http:` at the beginning, so inside `<head>` instead of:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

use:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: This worked for me too!  Do you know why removing http: fixes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it might benefit someone who stumbles upon it:

The issue here is that you cannot import the fonts with good old insecure **http**. It will work for your local enviroment, but not on Heroku.

You should use http**s** instead!

Do it like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```